# List To ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, observablecollection

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App**. It is getting **JSON from server** and **deserializing** it and **storing it into List**. I have **ListView** bound to this **List**. Now if the new items are added to List, ListView isn't updated. So, I am trying to convert change this List into **ObservableCollection**. But I am confused about samples and tutorials on internet.

**XAML:**

```
 <DataTemplate 
            x:Key="StandardProductsItemTemplate">
            <Grid >
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                      <Image 
                    Source="{Binding ProductImage}" 
                        x:Name="ImageDisplay"/>                        
                     <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**C#:**

```
List<Product> ProductsObject = new List<Product>();

 for (int i = 0; i < GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products.Count; i++)
            {
             ProductsObject.Add(GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i]); 
            }
ProductListView.ItemsSource = ProductsObject;
```

Now, I want to use **ObservableCollection** **instead** of **list** for ListView to remain Updated. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsObject = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

 for (int i = 0; i < GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products.Count; i++)
            {
             ProductsObject.Add(GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i]); 
            }
ProductListView.ItemsSource = ProductsObject;
```

Comment: What about this method they are using on internet samples:

Comment: private ObservableCollection<Product> timeStepDataCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<Product> TimeStepDataCollection_Method
        {
            get
            {
                if (timeStepDataCollection == null)
                {
                    timeStepDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
                }
                return timeStepDataCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                timeStepDataCollection = value;
            }
        }

Comment: You don't need to create a private variable of observable collection and set it's getter and setter methods, you can use it directly by initialising in your case. You just need to create a Observable Collection and pass it to the list view, if you want that collection to be used else where then just create a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace your list by an ObservableCollection, the syntax in your example stays the same:

```
ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsObject = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

 for (int i = 0; i < GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products.Count; i++)
     {
      ProductsObject.Add(GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i]); 
     }
ProductListView.ItemsSource = ProductsObject;
```

Comment: private ObservableCollection<Product> timeStepDataCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<Product> TimeStepDataCollection_Method
        {
            get
            {
                if (timeStepDataCollection == null)
                {
                    timeStepDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
                }
                return timeStepDataCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                timeStepDataCollection = value;
            }
        }

Comment: What about this method they are using on internet samples